# How to Access Parent Block ID and Index of Current InnerBlock in Gutenberg Custom Block?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks, acf-gutenberg

I'm working with Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) to create custom blocks for the WordPress Gutenberg editor. I have designed a parent block named "Tabs" that can contain multiple inner blocks, each named "Tab".

Here's a simple representation of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
// Parent Block: Tabs (render.php file)
<Tabs>
  <InnerBlocks />
</Tabs>

// InnerBlock: Tab (render.php file)
// Inside this block, I need to access the ID of the parent (Tabs) 
// and also the current index or position of this inner block (Tab).
```

My challenge is to access:

1. The ID of the parent block (Tabs) from inside each Tab inner block.
2. The current index or position of the Tab inner block within the
   inner block itself.

Given that I'm using ACF for block creation, how might I retrieve this information in the `render.php` file of my custom blocks?

Has anyone worked on something similar or can guide me through this?

Answer (score 0):

## Index

Maybe is not the better solution, but there is an approach
In your Tab.tsx you can add this :

```
  const index = select('core/block-editor').getBlockIndex(props.clientId);

  useEffect(() => {
    setAttributes({ index });
  }, [index, setAttributes]);
```

Of course you need to add index attributes when you register your component

## Parent Id

For the parent id, below an approach to get the context of your parent

```
  const parentClientId = select(
    'core/block-editor',
  ).getBlockHierarchyRootClientId(props.clientId);
  const parentAttributes = select('core/block-editor').getBlock(parentClientId);
```

## Parent Id #2

You have another approach that you can explore, it's to add context to Tabs.tsx

```
registerBlockType('stackoverflow/tabs', {
  title: 'tabs',
  description: 'tabs',
  category: 'widgets',
  attributes: {
    id: { type: 'string' },
  },
  providesContext: {
    id: 'id',
  },
  edit: YourEditFile,
  save: YourSaveFile,
});
```

And in Tab.tsx recover the context

```
registerBlockType('stackoverflow/tab', {
  usesContext: ['id'],
});
```

To read it in your Tab.tsx you can do this

```
const { id } = props.context;
```

## Php Only

### Provide Context

Provide your block id to child with the attribute

```php
// Parent block
register_block_type('plugin-name-parent', array(
  'editor_script' => 'script-name',
  'editor_style' => 'style-name',
  'render_callback' => 'render_callback_parent',
  'provides_context' => ['name_context', 'name_attribute'],
);

// Child block
register_block_type('plugin-name', array(
  'editor_script' => 'script-name',
  'editor_style' => 'style-name',
  'render_callback' => 'render_callback',
  'uses_context' => ['name_context'],
);

function render_callback($attributes, $content, $block)
{
  $context = $block->context['name_context']; // Can be your parent id
}
```

Comment: I'm using PHP though :)

Comment: Ah, i didn't read well, but anyway i have maybe a solution for you.
I'm editing my post